# como alterar o display da div pelo js?

Tags: javascript, css, javascript-eventos

Por algum motivo que desconheço dessa vez o browser não quer renderizar o código... basicamente eu preciso mudar o `display: nome` da `div` para `display: block`através do javascript.

```js
botaoSticky = function(e) {
    e.target.style.display = "none"
    aparecerSticky()
}

const aparecerSticky = function(){
    const mySticky = document.getElementsByClassName('sticky')
    mySticky.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
 .sticky{
    display: none;
    background: rgb(42, 197, 211);
    height: 30vh;
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 20px;

}
```

```html
   <aside>
       <input type="button" value="botão sticky" class="botao" onclick=botaoSticky(event)>
       <div class="sticky"><p>meu sticky</p></div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Falta o índice da classe do elemento. Se for o primeiro, seria: `document.getElementsByClassName('sticky')[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método [`.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) retorna uma lista de elementos, tipo array, e não um elemento só. Para isso funcionar deves fazer `document.getElementsByClassName('sticky')[0]` ou `document.querySelector('.sticky')`

```js
const botaoSticky = function(e) {
  e.target.style.display = "none";
  aparecerSticky();
}

const aparecerSticky = function() {
  const mySticky = document.querySelector('.sticky');
  mySticky.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.sticky {
  display: none;
  background: rgb(42, 197, 211);
  height: 30vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <input type="button" value="botão sticky" class="botao" onclick=botaoSticky(event)>
  <div class="sticky">
    <p>meu sticky</p>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: caramba é mesmo tinha esquecido desse detalhe ksksks vlw maninho sz